# Less Parse Error using ::before

Tags: parsing, less, syntax-error

I have this error:
ParseError: Unrecognised input , when I trying to set:

```
.my-style(@color: #66CCFF)::before{
    border-top-color: @color;
}
```

(There is some special way to use "before" in LESS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine parametric mixin declaration and CSS selectors in the same statement. Assuming you need to get something like this:

```css
some-selector::before {
    border-top-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The proper Less code would be:

```less
.my-style(@color: #66CCFF) {
    &::before {
        border-top-color: @color;
    }
}

// usage:
some-selector {
    .my-style(red);
}
```